# Iterate code over each text review in the list of texts, writing a loop

Tags: python, nlp

I am implementing Aspect-Based-Sentiment-Analysis.
My data look like:

```
        product  rating  body                   price_aspect    packaging_aspect   quality_aspect scent_aspect  difference_aspect

0   0   Elemis ...  1   I love ememis but...    I love ememis but..None None    None    None
1   1   Elemis ...  5   Great                       None           None None    None    None
3   3   Elemis ...  5   My husband loves it...      None           None None    None    None
4   4   Elemis ...  4   This product, although...   None           None None    None    None
```

The column "body" is the text of the review. The columns "price/packaging/etc/_aspect" include the text of the reviews (from column "body") where a certain aspect was mentioned. So here you see that aspect "price" was mentioned in the first review.

My goal is to define a sentiment of the review in column "price_aspect". I implement Aspect-Based-Sentiment-Analysis for this.
My code is here:

```
recognizer = absa.aux_models.BasicPatternRecognizer()
nlp = absa.load(pattern_recognizer=recognizer)
text = df.price_aspect[0]
completed_task = nlp(text=text, aspects=['price', 'packaging', 'quality', 'scent', 'difference'])
price, packaging, quality, scent, difference = completed_task.examples
absa.summary(price)
```

My output when I call absa.summary(price):

```
Sentiment.negative for "price"
Scores (neutral/negative/positive): [0.003 0.954 0.043]
```

This is nice and that is what I need. However, I want to iterate this code over each line in the column "price_aspect" at once, not only for one line (line 0 in my case). So I need to change `text = df.price_aspect[0]` in my code that will refer me to the next line (not only line 0). Do I need a loop here? Or should I write a loop here:`completed_task = nlp(text=text, aspects=['price', 'packaging', 'quality', 'scent', 'difference'])`?
Moreover, when I get the result in the form "Sentiment.negative for price" I want to append it into a new column as a string.
I am new to Python. Would you refer me to any source that solves my request?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need a loop here? Or should I write a loop here:completed_task = nlp(text=text, aspects=['price', 'packaging', 'quality', 'scent', 'difference'])?

What you want to do is:

df.price_aspect = df.price_aspect.apply(lambda t: nlp(text=t, aspects=['price', 'packaging', 'quality', 'scent', 'difference']))

See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.Series.apply) for more details.

Comment: when I run this code, I receive the following: `----> 7 completed_task = df_c.apply(lambda t: nlp(text=t, aspects=['price', 'packaging', 'quality', 'scent', 'difference']))
    424         output = []
    425         for char in text:
--> 426             cp = ord(char)
    427             if cp == 0 or cp == 0xFFFD or _is_control(char):
    428                 continue

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 129 found`

Comment: One of the possible reasons why this code should not work is that your nlp object expects to get a string as an input, while your column contains Nones. The solution is to apply this function to only the string values, while Nones remain unchanged:

df.price_aspect = df.price_aspect.apply(lambda t: nlp(text=t, aspects=['price', 'packaging', 'quality', 'scent', 'difference']) if t)